# Should C++ std::future<T> method be named is_ready() or ready()?

Tags: c++, future, c++-experimental

Why is the experimental name `is_ready()` [considered](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/is_ready) as an enhancement to `std::future` and not `ready()` which is more consistent with the STL coding style? Future already has a method called `valid()` which also doesn't have the `is_` prefix.

Interestingly both [N3721](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3721.pdf) and [N3865](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3865.pdf) contain both names.

Comment: _... which is more consistent ..._ - [are](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) [you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_partitioned) [sure](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_execution_policy) [about](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/named_comparison_functions) [that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/is_open)?

Comment: Honestly, there seem to be plenty of examples of both styles. I'm not sure there's a consistent bias one way or the other.

Comment: @Useless: To be fair, all of those are global functions, not member functions. Except for the last one, which comes from the IOStreams library that is well-known to use a different coding style from "STL".

Comment: True, and @S.M.'s answer looks reasonable. I'm just far from sure that the original claim about consistency holds up.

Comment: `is_open` is a good point. However in this case [open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) is a verb and an existing function. The `is_` prefix is used a lot for type traits and in general in namespace scope, but as far as I can see used rarely for member functions. The fact that both papers also mix it up made me curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's because of already existing enum constant `std::future_status::ready`. So `is_ready()` checks for the status `ready`. Although they both are in different naming scopes, I assume authors  wish to avoid name intersection.

Comment: I accept this answer because it sounds most reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

`<speculation>`

I suspect `is_ready()` is clearer.  When reading the code `if (future.is_ready())` almost sound english and obviously means that `is_ready` is `const`.  `if ( future.ready() )` sounds like it could mean "`future` needs to get ready, then return" or "`future` is already ready".

`</speculation>`

Comment: `vec.is_empty()` also sounds more English I guess (I'm not a native English speaker), but still `vec.empty()` is standardized.